# Giving multiple prompts over DM's

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I need a command to send 4 different messages to the user, each message with a new prompt, so for example "Prompt 1" and what ever the user responds will be pushed into an array called "config". I thought about using message collectors, but couldn't set it up to collect multiple answers.

**Pseudo code:**

```
 let config = new Array();

message.author.send("Prompt 1");
config.push(collected.answer).then(
    message.author.send("Prompt 2");
    config.push(collected.answer).then(
        ect...
)
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but can you please say where collected is defined?

Comment: Well that is Pseudo code, its not actually code, just meant to kind of show what I wanted. Thats why I wrote Pseudo code in bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN use message collectors. However, you need to have it in a variable. Here is an example:

```js
msg.author.send('some prompt').then(m => {
let i = 0;
var collector = m.channel.createMessageCollector(me => 
me.author.id === msg.author.id && me.channel === m.channel, {max: /*some number*/})
collector.on('collect', collected => {
if(collected.content === 'end') return collector.stop(); 
//basically if you want to stop all the prompts and do nothing
i +=1
if(i === 1) return collected.channel.send(/*something*/); //next prompt
if(i === 2) return collected.channel.send(/*something*/); //and so on until you get to the last prompt

})
collector.on('end', collectedMsgs => {
if(collectedMsgs.size < /*amount of prompts*/) {
return collectedMsgs.first().channel.send('Ended early, nothing was done.');
}
//some action you would do after all are finished
})
})
```

There may be some missing parentheses, you will have to add them.

Comment: Np, pls click the check mark to say that it is correct.