# Startup TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I've had multiple problems one after another. The first being;

> TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client

Which I solved by changing up my code from:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
```

To:

```
const { Client, Intents, Discord } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

But now I am running into a seperate issue. Where I keep getting this error;

> Startup TypeError: Cannot read property 'Collection' of undefined

This is really frustrated because I've been at this problem for a couple of hours. Any help would be massively appreciated!

All essential code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const { prefix, token, mongoPath } = require("./jsonFiles/config.json");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongo = require("./utility/mongo.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const Levels = require("discord-xp");

bot.login(token);

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./commands");

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    //Finds the name of the command
    const commandFiles = fs
        .readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`)
        .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}

bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log("Connect as " + bot.user.tag);
    //levels(bot);

    await mongo().then(() => {
        try {
            console.log("Connected to mongo!");
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    });

    bot.user.setActivity(".help", {
        type: "WATCHING",
    });
});

bot.on("message", async (message) => {
    try {
        await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
            Levels.setURL(mongoPath);

            if (!message.guild) return;
            if (message.author.bot) return;

            const randomAmountOfXp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1; // Min 1, Max 30
            const hasLeveledUp = await Levels.appendXp(
                message.author.id,
                message.guild.id,
                randomAmountOfXp
            );
            if (hasLeveledUp) {
                const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
                message.channel.send(
                    `${message.author}, congratulations! You have leveled up to **${user.level}** in \`${message.guild.name}\` :sunglasses:`
                );
            }
        });

        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
        const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        const command =
            bot.commands.get(commandName) ||
            bot.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

        if (!command) return;

        if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === "dm")
            return message.reply("I can't execute that command inside DMs!");

        if (command.permissions) {
            const authorPerms = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.author);
            if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permissions)) {
                if (message.author.id !== "344834268742156298") {
                    return message.reply("YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION (git gud scrub)");
                }
            }
        }

        if (command.creator === true && message.author.id !== "344834268742156298")
            return message.reply("Wait what, you are not creator man, you cannot use the command!!!!!");

        if (command.args === true && !args.length) {
            let reply = `You didn't provide a valid arguments, ${message.author}!`;

            if (command.usage) {
                reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
            }
            message.delete({
                timeout: 25 * 1000,
            });
            return message.channel.send(reply).then((message) => {
                message.delete({
                    timeout: 25 * 1000,
                });
            });
        }

        const { cooldowns } = bot;

        if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
            cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
        }

        const now = Date.now();
        const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
        const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown ?? 1.5) * 1000;

        if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
            const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

            if (now < expirationTime) {
                const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
                return message.reply(
                    `please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${
                        command.name
                    }\` command.`
                );
            }
        }

        timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
        setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

        const maxArguments = command.maxArgs || null;

        if (
            args.length < command.minArgs ||
            (maxArguments !== null && command.args === "true" && args.length > command.maxArgs)
        ) {
            let reply = `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
            return message.channel.send(reply);
        }

        try {
            command.execute(message, args, message.guild);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top you never defined `Discord` properly. You are trying to access the non-existant `Discord` property of the discord.js module with object destructuring. There are 2 quick fixes for this, the first one will be faster however.

```js
//at the top change the declaration of Client
const Discord = { 
    Client, 
    Intents 
} = require('discord.js')
//Discord is module discord.js
```

Or you can do

```js
const { 
    Collection, 
    Client, 
    Intents
 } = require('discord.js')
//use new Collection() instead of new Discord.Collection()
```

Comment: Please mark the question as correct with the checkmark if it helped! It also seems like you are saying thanks to other answers but not marking as correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/68048602/15781079

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
```

Try:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"), { Client, Intents } = Discord;
```

Or you can also import `Collection` from discord:

```js
const { Client, Intents, Collection } = require("discord.js");
```

and replace:
`new Discord.Collection()` with `new Collection()`